# Fill NULL of col a with value from col a if values of col b match

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, duplicates

Imagine I have `COUNTRY | POSTAL CODE` columns. There will be many duplicates but mostly, some `COUNTRY` values will be missing where `POSTAL CODE` will be present. How do I fill in `COUNTRY` with the value of `COUNTRY` in some other row where `POSTAL CODE` match?

Before

```
COUNTRY | POSTAL CODE
UK      | ABCXYZ
NULL    | ABCXYZ
```

After

```
COUNTRY | POSTAL CODE
UK      | ABCXYZ
UK      | ABCXYZ
```

Comment: So you want to update `country` with the value from a row where `postal_code = 'ABCXYZ' AND country IS NOT NULL`, but what if multiple rows are found, which row do you take country from?

Comment: If multiple rows are found where the value for country is not null and the postal code is the same, then those rows are going to be all the same. Like they'll all be "UK, ABCXYZ", "UK, ABCXYZ". I don't know how to write this in sql but *any* of those rows would make do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the next update it's what you need:

```sql
update table a
set country = b.country
FROM (select DISTINCT country, postal_code from table where country is not null) b
where a.postal_code = b.postal_code
and a.country is not null;
```

Comment: This will update not-null rows as well. Also change the subquery to do a `DISTINCT country, postal_code`, then you'll get a smaller table to look through.

Comment: If i adapt this query to my table I get `ERROR: column "table_name" of relation "table_name" does not exist`

Comment: `UPDATE officers_deduped
SET officers_deduped.address_country_norm = b.address_country_norm
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT address_country_norm, address_postal_code FROM officers_deduped WHERE address_country_norm IS NOT NULL) b
WHERE officers_deduped.address_postal_code = b.address_postal_code;`

Comment: can you give me the entire oracle error; with ora-code?

Comment: it seems that [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145719/column-table-name-of-relation-table-name-does-not-exist-sql-state-42703) you can find the solution to this last error. Please read it and change the script. I will edit now with the new code.

Comment: @F.Lazarescu `UPDATE table a SET field = b.field FROM (...) WHERE ... AND a.field IS NOT NULL`, otherwise you also update rows where `field` is already set.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set country = (select t2.country
                   from t t2
                   where t2.postal_code = t.postal_code and
                         t2.country is not null
                   limit 1
                  )
where t.country is not null;
```

This can take advantage of indexes on `(postal_code, country)` and `(country)`.  I think this should have the best performance for what you want to do.